# Difference between naming a constructor with the same name as a name of the class vs naming it with random name

Tags: java

I want to ask about java programming language, to be specific about constructors. Lets say we have a class test, where we are testing the whole program, and class point, where constructors are defined (set and get method btw).
Class line:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Point p = new Point();
        

        p.setX(10);
        System.out.println("X coordinate point1: " + p.getX());
        p.setY(20);
        System.out.println("Y coordinate point1: " + p.getY());
}
```

Class point:

```
public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
```

Now, would be a mistake if I put the name of the class Point in constructor:

`public void Point(int x) {         this.x = x;     }`

`public int Point(int x)`

`{         this.x = x;     }`

Logically, I suppose that I just need to rename the name of the constructor in the main method, but again, I'm not so sure about that.

I renamed the name of the constructor as class Point and in the main method as well, but, as I thought, it's wrong for some reason. It didn't show directly the error description

Comment: Didn't read the body of the question, but you can't name a constructor with a "random name". The syntax of declaring a constructor is *always* `[public/private] TheClassName([0 or more parameters]) { ... }`, where square brackets denote optionality

Comment: neither `public void Point(int x)`  nor `public int Point(int x)` would be a constructor for the class `Point` because constructors do not have return types. And a constructor name always has to match the class name by definition.

Comment: Hint: `public void Point(...) { ... }` or `public int Point(...) { ... }` do not declare a constructor but a method. Constructors are not allowed to declare a return type.

Comment: why would you do that? When I change a tire on my car, I don't say "hey, look! I'm creating a car", I say "I'm changing a tire". There is a good reason for having a different naming convention for constructors and setters.

Comment: The only thing that you can change for a constructors signature is the arguments it receives. So you can do `public Point()` for a no-args default constructor or `public Point(int x)` for a constructor that needs an int as argument for example

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think you are confused about constructors. They have two requirements:

- They have to have the same name as the enclosing class;
- They have no return type.

So no, `void Point()` is never a constructor. And within the `Point` class, anything other than `Point` will never be a constructor.

Note that writing `void Point()` is still valid (unfortunately), but it is not a constructor, but just a regular method which happens to have the same name as its enclosing class. The compiler can tell them apart, because their usage is never ambiguous. However, you **should never** give your method the same name as the enclosing class, as it is both confusing and it violates the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Also note that the compiler automatically generates a no-argument constructor for you if you don't define any constructor.

So this:

```java
class Point {
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```java
class Point {

    public Point() { }

    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Constructors do not have a return type.  For example,

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Trying to define it this way ...

```
public int Point(int x) {}
```

... is actually declaring a method, just confusingly with the same name as the class.